# Merging Event definitions for mixins and Views backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've created a mixin for backbone and I'm wondering if there is a better way than this to merge the events hash.

Mixin:

```
app.mixin.filter = {
events: {
    'click .label': 'toggle',
    'keyup .file-search': 'updateSearchFilter'
},
 //more stuff
}
```

View:

```
app.DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.contentwrap',

    dashEvents: {'click .project-btn': 'addProjectModal'},

    initialize: function() {

    //other stuff

    _.defaults(app.DashboardView.prototype.events, this.dashEvents);

    //other stuff

    }
}

 _.extend(app.DashboardView.prototype, app.mixin.filter);
```

I'm particularly not happy with calling the event hash dashEvents. Is there some way I can keep the events as 'events'? 
Or is there a standard pattern to handle this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.contentwrap',
  events : _.extend({}, app.mixin.filters.events, {
    'click .project-btn': 'addProjectModal'
  })
}
```

Comment: Actually I have just forgotten `events` prop in `app.mixin.filter`. But this is working approach. You was asking for pattern and I give it for you.

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk as I understand the problem is not only in extending events, but methods as well.

Comment: app.mixin.filters.events makes no difference.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle and I will help you

Comment: Its OK - I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way - all these solutions (including my own) are similarly 'workarounds' (I'm not being critical, just making a personal observation).

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this in my app:

```
app.DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend(_.defaults({
    el: '.contentwrap',

    events: _.defaults({ 
        'click .project-btn': 'addProjectModal'
    }, app.mixin.filter.events)

}, app.mixin.filter));
```

Here I came up with slightly different approach:

```
app.mixin.filter = function () {
  _.defaults(this.events, {
    'click .label': 'toggle',
    'keyup .file-search': 'updateSearchFilter'
  });
  _.defaults(this, {
    // more stuff
  });
}

app.DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.contentwrap',
    events: {'click .project-btn': 'addProjectModal'}
}

app.mixin.filter.call(app.DashboardView.prototype);
```

Comment: This is bad approach. Your mixins override your events

Comment: This satisfies my desire to not rename the events hash, I haven't tested it so don't know if it works - but it feels just as painful as my approach!

Comment: `View.prototype.events` can be function that returns events hash, maybe using this feature will somehow make the code look cleaner. I've  also simplified my 1st approach with using `_.defaults` instead of `_.extend` to avoid `{}`.